# Searching von strings in html-head with Cucumber

Tags: cucumber, watir, meta-tags, watir-webdriver

I'm wondering how if I can check the head of a HTML-document for existence of a particular string with cucumber.
Actually I'm interested in specific robots directives, so I launch in the first of my steps a browser (atm Firefox) and open a local site.

In the second step I check the entire html-code for a string:

```
@b.html.include?('<meta name="robots" content="noindex, follow">').should == true
```

And see my scenario failing at the second step. (expected true, got false)
Surprisingly a check for an partial string is succesfull:

```
@b.html.include?('name="robots"').should == true
```

But as soon as I check for

```
@b.html.include?('<meta name="robots"').should == true
```

or just

```
@b.html.include?('a name="robots"').should == true
```

I get a false again.

So, I thought the presence of whitespaces causes this behavior.
A quick check with only a bonus whitespace

```
@b.html.include?(' name="robots"').should == true
```

and the testscenario is green.

A search for a whole sentence in the document body

```
@b.html.include?('<h1>Yarr, that "is" supeb!</h1>').should == true
```

is also passing.

I've also tried to move the h1 heading into the head of the document (test still passing) and the meta-tag into the body (test is still failing)

I'm using cucumber 1.2.0 and ruby 1.9.3p0 with Firefox driven via watir-webdriver and wondering if I'm doing something wrong.
Actually I have just one feature with this simple steps and a minimal html-site with meta-data and this one "Yarr" sentence. No rails, no rake. OS X 10.7
Please tell me if I should provide more information… I'm tinkering with this stuff for hours.

**Edit1**: added the HTML of the site I check.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/public/stylesheets/main.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/public/images/favicon.png">
    <script src="/public/javascripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <link rel="canonical" href="google.de">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, follow">
  </head>
<body>
    <h1>Yarr, that "ist" superb!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide the HTML of your page? Also what are you using to drive the Firefox browser?

Comment: I've appended the HTML to my question. I'm using watir-webdriver 0.5.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The Problem:**

It seems that the properties of HTML tags will not always be in the order that they were written. See this:

```
puts @b.html
#=> <!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="/public/stylesheets/main.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/public/images/favicon.png" type="image/png" rel="shortcut icon" />
    <script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="/public/javascripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <link href="google.de" rel="canonical" />
    <meta content="noindex, follow" name="robots" />
  </head>
<body>
    <h1>Yarr, that "ist" superb!</h1>

</body></html>
```

Notice that the `<meta content="noindex, follow" name="robots" />` is not the same order as your HTML file. This explains why your tests are giving the results they are.

**Suggest Solution:**

Assuming that you only care that the particular meta tag appears in the header (and not the particular order the tag is written), I would suggest using:

```
b.head.meta(:name => 'robots', :content => 'noindex, follow').exists?.should == true
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your suggested snippet works as expected.